# Finding Pi kernel 3.10.x or 3.9.x Image to download

Tags: pi-2, kernel

From where can I get raspberry Pi kernel- 3.10.x or 3.9.x image for, to install on pi-2

Answer (score 1):

You can get them on the official github repository, here:

3.9:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.9.y

3.10:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.10.y

Comment: can you tell me how to compile the source code of kernel?

Comment: You can cross compile it from your machine by installing the toolchain. It is too long to explain it in a comment but you have a great tutorial here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

Comment: I am cross compiling Kernel 3.10.y from https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux 
on Ubuntu system
I am stuck with following error :

arch/arm/kernel/built-in.o:(___ksymtab+v6wbi_flush_kern_tlb_range+0x0): undefined reference to `v6wbi_flush_kern_tlb_range'
what could be the reason?